# How to wait in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

How can I wait after performing a task in corona.

```
timer.performwithdelay()
```

waits before performing a task but I want to wait after performing a task. Is there any way to do that.
Actually I want to display an image for 5 seconds.

Comment: google "corona wait", click first hit, read, implement...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
local image

function afterTimer()
    -- hide image
    image.alpha = 0 
    -- or use
    -- image.isVisible = false
    -- or remove it 
    -- display.remove(image); image = nil
end

image = display.newImage("nameOfImage.png")

timer.performWithDelay(5000, afterTimer, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html

https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/50088-how-to-wait-a-certain-amount-of-time/

```
function afterTimer()
    print("Timer is done!")
    print("Now do something else")
end

timer.performWithDelay(3000, afterTimer, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task you want to perform is just a transition (like fading out) on a `DisplayObject` after instantiating the object, keep in mind the `delay` parameter available on all the functions of the `transition` library in Corona.

For example, to hide your image 5 seconds after creating it:

```
local image = display.newImage(...
transition.fadeOut( image, { delay = 5000, time = 250 }
```

If you want to remove the `image` DisplayObject from the scene after it fades out, you could add a completion handler:

```
local image = display.newImage(...

local function onFadeOutComplete( obj )
    obj:removeSelf()
    obj = nil
end

transition.fadeOut( image, {delay = 5000, time = 250, onComplete = onFadeOutComplete } )
```